# WebView Refrescar o Actualizar

Tags: android-studio, webview

Me podrían informar como podría refrescar un WebView cada X segundos. No se mucho pero necesitaría Refrescar o Actualiza un WebView cada X segundo. Soy nuevo.
Estoy con el Android Studio 2020.3.1
Muchas Gracias a tod@s.

```
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnPlay, btnPause, btnActual, btnStop, btnSalir, btnFacebook, btnTwitter, btnInstagram, btnYouTube, btnWhatsApp;
WebView caratula, escuchemos, publi;
String stream = "https://radio.perustream.com:10991/stream";
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
boolean prepared = false;
boolean started = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swiperContainer)
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    //new PlayerTask().execute(stream);
    caratula = findViewById(R.id.caratula);
    caratula.clearHistory();
    caratula.getSettings();
    caratula.setBackgroundColor(0x00FFFFFF);
    caratula.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    caratula.loadUrl("https://www.cloud-music.es/portada.html");
    caratula.loadUrl("javascript:widows.location.reload(true)");
    publi = findViewById(R.id.publi);
    publi.clearHistory();
    publi.getSettings();
    publi.setBackgroundColor(0x00FFFFFF);
    publi.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    publi.loadUrl("https://www.cloud-music.es/titulo1.php");
    publi.loadUrl("javascript:widows.location.reload( true )");
    escuchemos = findViewById(R.id.escuchemos);
    escuchemos.clearHistory();
    escuchemos.getSettings();
    escuchemos.setBackgroundColor(0x00FFFFFF);
    escuchemos.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

escuchemos.loadUrl("https://Fps1.listen2myradio.com:2199/listen.php?ip=95.154.228.`

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugerimos revisar [ask], agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, saludos.

Comment: Saludos Antonio, como buena practica es recomendado que al momento de crear una pregunta al menos se provea una breve porción del código que estas teniendo dificultad. Bienvenido y happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias investigando cambie mirando y cambie lo siguiente 1 por cada WebView añadiendo al String url cambio de nombre para diferenciarlos y al view igual:

```
String url = "https://www.cloud-music.es/portada.html";
    WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.caratula);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    view.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Hola, si esto es una respuesta te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.